# Trying to call a static method from xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For my university project, I have to set up a bank application and, as part of the app, we have to determine whether or not a person is eligible to open up a bank account based on their income and age. So far I have got:

```
public static bool AllowedStatus(decimal income, int age)
    {
        if ((income > minIncome) && (age > minAge))
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and in the xaml.cs file, I've got:

```
private void CreateAccountButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (activeAccount.AllowedStatus() == true)
        {
            //ACCOUNT CREATED MESSAGE
        }
        else
        {
            //ACCOUNT INVALID MESSAGE
        }
    }
```

but I keep getting the message "No overload for method 'AllowedStatus' takes 0 arguments.

How do I get the if statement in CreateAccountButton_Click to check the bool in the AllowedStatus method so I can do the rest of the statement?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: In your CreateAccountButton_Click handler, where are you supposed to be getting the income and age?  Is that from other controls on your form?

Comment: You're declaring your method as `AllowedStatus(decimal income, int age)`. So obviously, you should pass some arguments to it in `activeAccount.AllowedStatus()`

Comment: @ Andy Korneyev when I tried that, it showed the message "invalid expression term 'decimal'".  I want to feed the parameters in from whatever the user inputs into the text box.

Comment: @TomAtkinson what value you pass to income variable?

Comment: Based on your comments here and beneath answers below, I'm voting to close this question as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @Sakura 's answer below has solved my problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want pass a decimal from yourTextBox then you can use:

```
private void CreateAccountButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    decimal income;
    int age;
    if (decimal.TryParse(yourIncomeTextBox.Text, out income)
        && int.TryParse(yourAgeTextBox.Text, out age)
        && activeAccount.AllowedStatus(income, age))
    {
        //ACCOUNT CREATED MESSAGE
    }
    else
    {
        //ACCOUNT INVALID MESSAGE
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to parse the text boxes first  but this has solved my issue now.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your method to have two parameters: AllowedStatus(decimal income, int age). You have to provide the two parameters when calling the method in your CreateAccountButton_Click.

```
private void CreateAccountButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (activeAccount.AllowedStatus(10000, 20) == true) **<-- You have to provide values here**
        {
            //ACCOUNT CREATED MESSAGE
        }
        else
        {
            //ACCOUNT INVALID MESSAGE
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's all well and good, but how do I feed in those parameters from the textbox in the app interface

Comment: @TomAtkinson That is another question. In fact, it is a "go and read a tutorial for WPF" question.

Comment: @TomAtkinson There is a method `FindName` with which you can find a control by name. Then convert it to Textbox and .Text prop.

Comment: in your xaml specify the name attribute for your textboxes. Then in your code behind instead of passing `AllowedStatus(10000, 20)` pass in `AllowedStatus((Convert.ToDecimal(textbox1name.Text), Convert.ToInt16(textbox2name.Text))`